# .less: not to compile variable file

Tags: less

On windows I'm using WinLESS to compile my .less files but I've come across a minor issue.

I have several files which import my core variables.less file. It has nothing but variables. When WinLESS compiles, it generates a blank variables.css file as well. Is there a way to stop this blank file from being created?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the latest version (1.3.0) then No, I'm afraid there isn't.

But you should raise a bug on https://github.com/dotless/dotless

I am a developer their and I'll look at it soon..

[Edit]

There is some wanted behaviour - if you change a file and it goes from being non-empty to empty, you would want it to update. However if the input file is a wildcard AND the output is empty AND the file doesn't exist, maybe it shouldn't be created.

What if there is just a bug in the less file causing it to output nothing? But this discussion should be moved to a github bug.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your file is unchecked in winless window?

I use it as in the screenshot below and don't get empty files.

[image: Winless screenshot]